# Plot rectangle points given height, width, number points

Tags: radicals, rectangles

Is it possible to plot the points of a rectangle given the **width**, **height** and **number of points** all within a for-loop using sin/cos or something similar. I'm trying to find an easy way to plot these points in consecutive order.

One thing to mention is that the points would always be a multiple of 4.

[image]

Comment: A square has the same width and height. A right-angled quadrilateral whose width and height may not be the same is called a "rectangle".

Comment: But more importantly: what points are you trying to plot? A rectangle has infinitely many points.To plot them, you draw lines, not individual points.

Comment: I want to plot find the points scene in the image above. 1 in each corner and 4 between each corner

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "consecutive order", you mean as one travels around the perimeter. Sine and cosine are not well suited for this. The angles between adjacent points change as you go around.

The simplest way is just to use 4 loops: Starting that `(x0, y0)` as the lowest coordinate corner, with width `w` and height `h`, and having `n + 1` points per side (counting both corners, so `n = 4` in your example), you can do:

```
dw = w / n
dh = h / n
x1 = x0 + w
y1 = y0 + h
for i = 0 to n - 1
    plot (x0 + i * dw, y0)
next i
for i = 0 to n - 1
    plot (x1, y + i * dh)
next i
for i = 0 to n - 1
    plot (x1 - i * dw, y1)
next i
for i = 0 to n - 1
    plot (x0, y1 - i * dh)
next i
```